# Endorsement Policy and Business Logic

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I need your guidance for the following case :

There are 3 Orgs namel A, B and C. A is the assets owner while B and C are asset maintainer. Initially B is maintaining assets of A. Now, asset maintenance is to be transferred from B to C with the approval of A, B and C. But, in case of some assets, C is not willing to take over the maintenance of them from B due to some technical causes.
Now,  I am able to change the maintainer from B to C. But, for cases where C is not willing to take over maintenance, how to incorporate such cases in Hyperledger Fabric using Endorsement Policy ?

Comment: You can write the logic in Chaincode. Check for the asset for which C is not willing to take over the maintenance and reject the maintenance transfer request with appropriate message.

Comment: Are you already using key level policies? Check: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html#setting-key-level-endorsement-policies